# Mbus protocol date format type G

Tags: python, c, datetime

Обращаюсь к  датчику  по технологии LoraWan, высылаю набор байтов(M-bus протокол) для запроса показаний. И необходимо передать два байта, содержащие информацию о сегодняшней дате, например hex 8323 соответствует 03.03.2020. В документации написано, что это формат Type G:Compound CP16:Date. Подскажите, кто-нибудь работал с указанным протоколом. Как преобразовать текущую дату  03.03.2020 в требуемый формат hex 8323?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void make_date(
    int year,     // years from 1900
    int month,    // 1-12
    int day,      // 1-31
    unsigned char* packet)   // [out], contains 2 bytes
{
    packet[0] = (unsigned char)( (day & 0x1F) | (((year - 100) & 7) << 5) );
    packet[1] = (unsigned char)( (month & 0xF) | ((((year - 100) & 0xF0) >> 3) << 4) );

    //packet[0] = (unsigned char)(day & 0x1F);
    //unsigned char tmp = (((year - 100) & 7) << 5);
    //packet[0] |= tmp;

    //packet[1] = (unsigned char)(month & 0xF);
    //unsigned char tmp1 = (unsigned char)((((year - 100) & 0xF0) >> 3) << 4);
    //packet[1] |= tmp1;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned char packet[2];

    make_date(2020 - 1900, 3, 3, packet);

    printf("%x %x\n", (int)packet[0], (int)packet[1]);   // 83, 23

    return 0;
}
```

Закомментированный код делает то же самое по этапам, чтобы было понятно.